# How do I sort css selectors with vim?

Tags: css, sorting, vim

I want to alphabetize css selectors (and properties) in my scss files. I'm sure vim can do this (even if I need to use some external tool). How would you sort the following?

```
h2 { 
  color:red;
  background-color:green;
}
h1 {
  font-size:12px;
}
```

To this:

```
h1 {
  font-size:12px;      
}
h2 {
  background-color:green;
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: it is not a good idea to sort selectors in CSS file, because it will break Cascade rule of CSS, in consequence of the site would be broken in markup

Comment: @VladimirStarkov Not necessarily. While I know this behavior is available, it should never be used imo. I hate the idea of having a 1000+ lines of code where order matters. How can you possibly keep all that context in your head? No, if order is being used to define styles than it's a code smell.

Comment: @VladimirStarkov here's one, not cleaned/consolidated, but working. Are there trouble spots in here where re-ordering would destroy things? http://pastie.org/4810691 I'm not saying that re-ordering _can't_ break things, I'm just saying by convention I don't want style sheets written with that fragility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your simple example the following two snippets seem to work, however I fear they may fall down with larger, more complex css.

---

To order the properties I used a macro**:

```
:let @q = "/{^Mvi{:sort^M"|%norm! @q
```

<sup>** Note that the ^M's here are entered with <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-m</kbd>.</sup>

Explanation:

1. Define a macro to:

   - Search for a "{"
   - Select text between "{" and "}"
   - Sort the selection by line
2. Run the macro across all lines in the buffer.

---

To order the selectors I used substitute and sort:

```
:%s/\v([^}])\n/\1/g|%sort|%s/\v[;{]/&\r/g
```

Explanation:

1. For every line that begins with something other than "}" remove the newline to collapse this block down to a single line.
2. Sort the buffer linewise.
3. After every ";" or "{" insert a newline.

Trailing whitespace throws this off a bit but you don't have any of that, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [**CSScomb**](http://csscomb.ru/). This tool sorts your css in cusomizable way. You can try it [**online**](http://csscomb.ru/online/#).

CSScomb has [plugin](https://github.com/miripiruni/CSScomb-for-Vim/) for Vim.

From the CSScomb's site:

- Sorting CSS properties *(The order of properties in the help of professionals)*
- Setting the order of CSS properties *(Use the order to which you are accustomed to)*

Comment: Right, I saw this in my search. As far as I can tell it doesn't sort selectors (as asked for in the question). Am I mistaken?

Comment: @thedeeno sorting selectors will breake your site hard — I previously told about it in comment to you question